# Changing Snippet syntax to use this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am just building a small snippet to hide a div checkout my snippet :

```
var Modal = function(){
            Modal.prototype.hide = function(elem){
                return elem.hide(); 
         // i basically want to change the above line to this.hide();
            }
        }

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var _str = new Modal();
                var div = $('#mydiv');
                _str['hide'](div);

            });
```

now , the reason i built this snippet is because i wanted to understand the code in modal.js and how it works , lets checkout the code in modal.js .

checkout this line :

```
data[option](_relatedTarget)
```

data is basically an instance of Modal

[option] is basically Modal.prototype.toggle(param)

and (_relatedTarget) is basically the parameter being passed .

so basically whats happening on that line is , the following function is being called .

hide(_relatedtarget).

I console.logged _relatedtarget and found out , it is basically an HTML element , looks something like below :

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

if you have a look at the toggle function , it looks something like below :

```
Modal.prototype.toggle = function (_relatedTarget) {
    return this.isShown ? this.hide() : this.show(_relatedTarget)
  }
```

so bascially we are passing the following parameter in the above function :

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

and it all works fine .

Now , lets review th hide function in my code :

```
Modal.prototype.hide = function(elem){
                return elem.hide(); 
            }
```

see how my hide function differs in the sense that, i am using the following syntax to hide my code :

```
elem.hide();
```

whereas the code in modal.js uses the following syntax :

```
this.hide()
```

but if i use the above syntax and run my code , the code does't work and the element is not hidden.

so my question is, how can i change the syntax in my code to :

`this.hide()` and make my code work, Fiddle of my example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rk1ruw2s/) .

Thank you .

Alexander.

Comment: any good reason for a downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this function to work without a parameter, the div needs to be known by the `Modal`. You could do it by passing the container's selector to your constructor, like so:

```
var _str = new Modal('#modal-container');
```

And assigning it as a property of `Modal`. Example code:

```js
var Modal = function(containerSelector) {
  this.container = $(containerSelector);

  Modal.prototype.hide = function() {
    return this.container.hide();
  }
}

// Using a setTimeout for the demo, so you can see it first
setTimeout(function() {

  var _str = new Modal('#modal-container');
  _str['hide']();

},1000);
```

```css
#modal-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This div will hide after 1 second:</p>
<div id="modal-container"></div>
```

**Edit**: don't confuse jQuery's `hide()` function (called on DOM elements) with your own (called on a `Modal` object). Check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvjony7f/), it implements a `toggle()` function just like you have at line `48`.

Comment: thanks for ur reply , but see how in the twitter bootstrap code https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L48 (Line 48)  , only `this.hide()` is used , not `this.container.hide();` .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I added a little something at the bottom of my answer, which replicates what you are talking about.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Glad it helped! Having different `hide()` functions can be a little confusing. The only difference is the type of the object it is called on.